# Problem with 2 slide show

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, helix3

1. SP Smart Slider (optima slider): the image is not at the centered
2. Unite Revolution Slider 2: the sub menu is hiding behind the revolution slider and it does not appear unless you scroll down.

SP Smart Slider at homepage,Unite Revolution Slider 2 at revolution menu item my

SP PAGE BUILDER Version 1.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the SP Smart SLider:

if you add this rule in your template CSS it would center the image:

```
.sp-slider-thumb > img { margin: 0 auto;}
```

Hope it solves your problem